# Removing nativescript modal on refresh

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I tried to remove nativescript modal by refreshing the whole route, but it didn't work.
Also using closeCallback() function didn't work outside the modal component.

Any other suggestions?